# css menu naming convention

Tags: css, naming-conventions

I'm stuck with a problem. It is good practice to create classnames that are describing. For example, `content-nav` and `widget-area`. I've this menu at the top of the site that has the following links:

1. Home
2. English (language dependant)
3. Contact
4. Sitemap
5. Terms & conditions
6. Disclaimer

How would you semantically call such a menu? In previous projects I referred to it as an `top-menu`, but that name is **related to graphical presentation and not good practice** in my opinion.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Uhh, something like `main-navbar`? I think you're making this more complicated than it need be!

Comment: There is already a content navigation, so my point is: how do you call this type of menu? Almost everysite has something like this. There some legal stuff and site-structure/functionality, but i can't think of a good name.

Comment: main-menu or main-nav. Since it's the main menu of the website, right?

Comment: I wouldn't refer to it as the main navigation, because it isn't. The big content-navigation is more or less the "main" navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My collegue uses the name `meta-navigation`, which in this case suits best. Or do you guys have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I usually go with `secondary-navigation` or `secondary-menu` to complement the `primary-navigation`/`primary-menu`